# Pytorch loss.items() cause irrecoverable CUDA illegal memory access on Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a [Coursera version Pix2pix](https://github.com/amanchadha/coursera-gan-specialization/blob/main/C3%20-%20Apply%20Generative%20Adversarial%20Network%20(GAN)/Week%202/C3W2B_Assignment.ipynb). The script can be smoothly trained on my personal Ubuntu laptop with a RTX3080Ti 16GB.
However, when I train it on Google Colab Pro (`nvidia-smi` indicates a P100 16GB), the line `mean_discriminator_loss += disc_loss.item() / display_step` always causes CUDA error illegal memory access at exactly the 33th iteration being trained (around 5GB GPU memory occupied).
Even worse, after this error happens, the 5GB cache will stuck in GPU memory and most of the torch functions will cause the same illegal memory access error, including `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`. And I cannot find the process that occupies the memory so I have to restart my session.
After I added `os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = '1'`, `gen_loss.backward()` causes error instead, with a different message, but still at the 33th iteration and brings the same memory occupying problem.

Error message before adding `os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = '1'`:

```
0%
33/24682 [00:11<2:01:04, 3.39it/s]
Pretrained initial state
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e8ba80389969> in <module>()
      9         disc = disc.apply(weights_init)
     10 
---> 11 train()

<ipython-input-9-4db64dc16c20> in train()
     31                         gen_opt.step()
     32 
---> 33                         mean_discriminator_loss += disc_loss.item() / display_step
     34                         mean_generator_loss += gen_loss.item() / display_step
     35 

RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Error message after adding `os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = '1'`. I cannot see anything by running the code snippet, since `torch.randn` causes illegal memory access error as mentioend above. But this snippet can be run without problem in a new lab page with a same configuration.

```
0%
33/24682 [00:13<2:24:50, 2.84it/s]
Pretrained initial state
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e8ba80389969> in <module>()
      9         disc = disc.apply(weights_init)
     10 
---> 11 train()

2 frames
<ipython-input-8-4db64dc16c20> in train()
     28                         gen_opt.zero_grad()
     29                         gen_loss = get_gen_loss(gen, disc, real, condition, adv_criterion, recon_criterion, lambda_recon)
---> 30                         gen_loss.backward()
     31                         gen_opt.step()
     32 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    361                 create_graph=create_graph,
    362                 inputs=inputs)
--> 363         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
    364 
    365     def register_hook(self, hook):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    173     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    174         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 175         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    176 
    177 def grad(

RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
You can try to repro this exception using the following code snippet. If that doesn't trigger the error, please include your original repro script when reporting this issue.

import torch
torch.backends.cuda.matmul.allow_tf32 = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = False
torch.backends.cudnn.allow_tf32 = True
data = torch.randn([1, 256, 63, 63], dtype=torch.float, device='cuda', requires_grad=True)
net = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=[2, 2], padding=[1, 1], stride=[1, 1], dilation=[1, 1], groups=1)
net = net.cuda().float()
out = net(data)
out.backward(torch.randn_like(out))
torch.cuda.synchronize()

ConvolutionParams 
    data_type = CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT
    padding = [1, 1, 0]
    stride = [1, 1, 0]
    dilation = [1, 1, 0]
    groups = 1
    deterministic = false
    allow_tf32 = true
input: TensorDescriptor 0x7672310
    type = CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT
    nbDims = 4
    dimA = 1, 256, 63, 63, 
    strideA = 1016064, 3969, 63, 1, 
output: TensorDescriptor 0x7673e30
    type = CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT
    nbDims = 4
    dimA = 1, 256, 64, 64, 
    strideA = 1048576, 4096, 64, 1, 
weight: FilterDescriptor 0x8df942a0
    type = CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT
    tensor_format = CUDNN_TENSOR_NCHW
    nbDims = 4
    dimA = 256, 256, 2, 2, 
Pointer addresses: 
    input: 0x7fe8f2ba0c00
    output: 0x7fe8a2000000
    weight: 0x7fe903800000
Additional pointer addresses: 
    grad_output: 0x7fe8a2000000
    grad_input: 0x7fe8f2ba0c00
Backward data algorithm: 1
```

Training script (with `Unet` and `Discriminator` from [this Coursera archive](https://github.com/amanchadha/coursera-gan-specialization/blob/main/C3%20-%20Apply%20Generative%20Adversarial%20Network%20(GAN)/Week%202/C3W2B_Assignment.ipynb)):

```
adv_criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() 
recon_criterion = nn.L1Loss()
lambda_recon = 250

prev_epochs = -1

n_epochs = 500
input_dim = 3
real_dim = 3
display_step = 10000
checkpoint_step = 10000
batch_size = 1
lr = 0.01
target_shape = 512
device = 'cuda'

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])
dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder("/content/Train", transform=transform)
gen = UNet(input_dim, real_dim).to(device)
gen_opt = torch.optim.Adam(gen.parameters(), lr = lr)
disc = Discriminator(input_dim + real_dim).to(device)
disc_opt = torch.optim.Adam(disc.parameters(), lr = lr / 10)

def combine_vectors(x, y):
    return torch.cat((x.float(), y.float()), 1)

def weights_init(m):
    if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(m, nn.ConvTranspose2d):
        torch.nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0.0, 0.02)
    if isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
        torch.nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0.0, 0.02)
        torch.nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

def get_gen_loss(gen, disc, real, condition, adv_criterion, recon_criterion, lambda_recon):
    fake = gen(condition)
    disc_fake = disc(fake, condition)
    adv_loss = torch.sum(adv_criterion(disc_fake, torch.ones_like(disc_fake)))
    recon_loss = lambda_recon * recon_criterion(fake, real)
    gen_loss = adv_loss + recon_loss
    return gen_loss

def recoverImage(image):
    return (image * 255).to(torch.uint8)

def train():
    mean_generator_loss = 0
    mean_discriminator_loss = 0
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    cur_step = 0

    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        for image, _ in tqdm(dataloader):
            image_width = image.shape[3]
            condition = image[:, :, :, image_width // 2:]
            condition = nn.functional.interpolate(condition, size=target_shape)
            real = image[:, :, :, :image_width // 2]
            real = nn.functional.interpolate(real, size=target_shape)
            condition = condition.to(device)
            real = real.to(device)

            disc_opt.zero_grad()
            with torch.no_grad():
                fake = gen(condition)
            disc_fake_hat = disc(fake.detach(), condition)
            disc_fake_loss = adv_criterion(disc_fake_hat, torch.zeros_like(disc_fake_hat))
            disc_real_hat = disc(real, condition)
            disc_real_loss = adv_criterion(disc_real_hat, torch.ones_like(disc_real_hat))
            disc_loss = (disc_fake_loss + disc_real_loss) / 2
            disc_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
            disc_opt.step()

            gen_opt.zero_grad()
            gen_loss = get_gen_loss(gen, disc, real, condition, adv_criterion, recon_criterion, lambda_recon)
            gen_loss.backward()
            gen_opt.step()

            mean_discriminator_loss += disc_loss.item() / display_step
            mean_generator_loss += gen_loss.item() / display_step

            if (cur_step % display_step == 0):
                if cur_step > 0:
                    print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Step {cur_step}: Generator (U-Net) loss: {mean_generator_loss}, Discriminator loss: {mean_discriminator_loss}")
                else:
                    print("Pretrained initial state")
                mean_generator_loss = 0
                mean_discriminator_loss = 0
                sampleFake = recoverImage(fake[0].to('cpu'))
                sampleReal = recoverImage(real[0].to('cpu'))
                sampleCondition = recoverImage(condition[0].to('cpu'))
                sample = torch.cat((sampleCondition, sampleReal, sampleFake), 2)
                write_jpeg(sample , "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Result/"+ str(cur_step) + ".jpg")
            cur_step += 1
    
        torch.save({'gen': gen.state_dict(),
            'gen_opt': gen_opt.state_dict(),
            'disc': disc.state_dict(),
            'disc_opt': disc_opt.state_dict()
        }, f"/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Checkpoints/pix2pix_{epoch + prev_epochs + 1}.pth")
```

Comment: This looks like some sort of dimension error somewhere before you call `loss.items()`, most likely within `get_gen_loss`.

Comment: Running this in CPU should give you the actual error